# VTIGER REST API Query string not accepting fields SELECTION

Tags: rest, api, vtiger

my simple GET request with firstname field:

```
<service_url>?operation=query&sessionName=<sessionID>&query=select%20*%20firstname%20from%20Contacts;
```

This yields the following response error:

> {"success":false,"error":{"code":"QUERY_SYNTAX_ERROR","message":"Syntax Error on line 1: token 'firstname' Unexpected Unknown(firstname), expected one of: FRM,COMMA"}}

While if i just leave out the "firstname" field selection it works well:

```
<service_url>?operation=query&sessionName=<sessionID>&query=select%20*%20from%20Contacts;
```

yeilding a full JSON list of contacts and their details.

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add star (*) in front of firstname ?

Comment: My first instinct was also to remove it when i actually put forth items do select, but if i do so the page doesn't reply with any response at all just a redirect to root.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following GET request in a browser:

https://your_vtiger_url/webservice.php/?operation=query&query=select%20firstname%20from%20Contacts;&sessionName=3151a01859207d8359052

and it worked just fine. Try using the same URL structure by replacing the base URL and sessionName. Test it in a browser first (if you haven't).

Comment: alright interesting. Yeah i tried it a lot just in a browser address line. Also with plenty of different sessions. So this basically means there's some problem with my vtiger installation on the domain or something....

Ok, good to have this feedback to locate the problem better.

Comment: Do you have contacts in your vtiger? Have you taken a look at the HTTP response sent back by the server (press F12 in chrome and you can see that info in the debugger)

Comment: I have a few contacts to test on. I look at the network but it doesn't say much, I only get a 302 response redirecting me back to root.

Can't understand this.

Comment: I even reinstalled vtiger just now and it still gives me the same problem..

Comment: My guess is that the query itself is perfectly fine. Because, when it's not, you get the syntax error. It seems that the request is processed correctly and then something else sends back the redirect (302). I'm not sure if that would be apache or Vtiger iteslf.

Comment: Have you tried different queries (to get accounts for example) or just to get the record count? Have you tried logging php errors?

Comment: So i've started to php log. There working query (asterisk) is logged. However the non-working one isn't logged at all. I'm starting to think it just doesn't make it to the server for some bizarre reason. There's no error log or output. Just the redirection to root.

Would such a thing mean i need to focus on apache?

Comment: I would try the following: 1) Installing Vtiger on a different environment and see if the error continues. For example in a hosting account. 2) Try to debug vtiger. Go to vtiger_root/include/Webservices, find the relevant files and do some echos to see if you can figure something out. 3) Concentrate on Apache (I wouldn't know how to go about this one).

Comment: If you can solve the problem remember to post back ;)